# Unable to insert data into Sqlite table (Java Netbeans)

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, netbeans

I'm making an application in Java, and one of the parts of the application is a button which reads data from `jtextfields`, splits them, and puts them into a database table. I'm not getting any error messages, and almost everything is working except for inserting data in the database table. The code looks like this:

```
private void Zawodnicy2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                           
    try{

        String zaw = zawodnik.getText();
        System.out.println(zaw);

        String zaw1 = zaw;
        String[] parts = zaw1.split(", ");
        String koszulka = parts[0]; 
        String nazwisko = parts[1]; 
        String wiek = parts[2]; 
        System.out.println(koszulka + ":::" + nazwisko + ":::" + wiek);
        listaDane.addElement(nazwisko);
        Lista.setModel(listaDane);

        String[] parts1 = nazwisko.split(" ");
        String nazw = parts1[0]; 
        String imie = parts1[1]; 

        String poz = pozycja.getText();
        System.out.println(poz);
        String poz1 = poz;
        String[] parts2 = poz1.split(": ");
        String pozyc = parts2[0]; 
        String pozycj = parts2[1]; 
        System.out.println(pozycj);

        String og = ogolem.getText();
        System.out.println(og);
        String og1 = og;
        String[] parts3 = og1.split(": ");
        String ogoltext = parts3[0]; 
        String ogol = parts3[1]; 
        System.out.println(ogol);


        pst=conn.prepareStatement("Insert into TEAM1Druzyna (NrKoszulki, Nazwisko, Imie, Pozycja, Punkty) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, koszulka);
        pst.setString(2, nazw);
        pst.setString(3, imie);
        pst.setString(4, pozycj);
        pst.setString(5, ogol);

        pst.execute();


       System.out.println("wpisano do tabeli " + nazwisko);

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `conn.commit()` after executing the statement (or is autocommit enabled)?

Comment: Use executeUpdate and make sure you commit the transaction (and close your resources)